# how to read xml file and fetch to C# Collections

Tags: c#, xml

I want the below xml data into C# application (fetch into any Collections)

```
<ns0:BookStore xmlns:ns0="http://Book.BookStore">
  <ns1:BookDetails xmlns:ns1="http://Book.BookDetails">
  <ns1:Name>ns0:Name_0</ns1:Name> 
  <ns1:PurchaseDate>1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00</ns1:PurchaseDate> 
  <ns1:SlNo>10</ns1:SlNo> 
  </ns1:BookDetails>

  <ns2:BookDetails xmlns:ns2="http://Book.BookDetails">
  <ns2:Name>ns0:Name_0</ns2:Name> 
  <ns2:PurchaseDate>1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00</ns2:PurchaseDate> 
  <ns2:SlNo>10</ns2:SlNo> 
   </ns2:BookDetails>

  <ns3:BookDetails xmlns:ns3="http://Book.BookDetails">
  <ns3:Name>ns0:Name_0</ns3:Name> 
  <ns3:PurchaseDate>1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00</ns3:PurchaseDate> 
  <ns3:SlNo>10</ns3:SlNo> 
  </ns3:BookDetails>
</ns0:BookStore>
```

As like below 3 results in C# Windows Application.

```
1: Combination of  <ns1:PaurchaseDate> + <ns1:SlNo> + <ns1:Id>

2: Combination of  <ns2:PaurchaseDate> + <ns2:SlNo> + <ns2:Id>

3: Combination of  <ns3:PaurchaseDate> + <ns3:SlNo> + <ns3:Id>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried for datatable but xml file nodes are different (like n1:Name,n2:Name,n3:Name) thats its fail to fetch data into datatable         table.ReadXml(stream); by using this function

Comment: Have you tried XmlSerializer to deserialize the xml file?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".